# How to switch one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

please help I'm stuck on this problem. I'm only able to see data of first fragment-1, but when I'm swipe right, there's no data of fragment-2.

```
ViewPager pager;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

}
 private class myPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public myPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
            switch(pos){            
            case 0: 
                return  new Artists();          
            case 1:             
                return new Songs();
            default:                
                return null;
            }
        }
        public int getCount() {
            return 2;
        }                  
   }
```

// Fragment-2 Codes:-

private ArrayListsongsList = new ArrayList();

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.songs_activity, container, false);     
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    // whatever you want to do!!
    Context context = null;
    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+ "!=0";
    String sortOrder = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER;
    String[] projection = {
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
    };

    // now we need to query for taking song's data from sd card
    Cursor cursor = this.getActivity().managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, selection, null, null);

    while(cursor.moveToNext()){
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(0));
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(1));
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(2));
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(3));
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(4));
        songsList.add(cursor.getString(5));
    }

    ListView lv = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

    int a[]= new int[]{R.id.txt1 ,R.id.txt2};

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this.getActivity(),
            R.layout.play_item, cursor, new String[]{MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST}, a);

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int songIndex1 = position;

            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity().getBaseContext(),Musik.class);

            i.putExtra("songIndex", songIndex1);            
            startActivity(i);
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: can you post code for songs?

Comment: when I put songs class at case-1. It shows  all related data of songs when I swipe right for another fragments, there's no any data of fragments 2, both class work fine at case-1 inside of switch function.

Comment: write a log on fragment 2's oncreate and check if fragment two is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the codepath tutorial for using viewPager with Fragment
https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

I think this is wrong,

```
PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

instead use

```
FragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new myPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Comment: Why are you using onActivityCreated inside a Fragment class Songs. use onCreate, onCreateView methods